# How to replace the label of select with its value?

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="timeformat" id="timeformat-a" value="am/pm" checked="checked" /> <b>am/pm</b> 
<input type="radio" name="timeformat" id="timeformat-b" value="24 hours" /> <b>24 hours</b>
        <select id="default-start-time" class="select check-list">
             <option value="" label="--Select--">--Select--</option>
             <option value="00:00" label="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
             <option value="00:30" label="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
             <option value="01:00" label="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
             <option value="01:30" label="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
             <option value="02:00" label="02:00 AM" selected>02:00 AM</option>
             <option value="02:30" label="02:30 AM">02:30 AM</option>
        </select>
```

When i choose the 24 hours format the option values should display.

jquery:

```
$("input[name='timeformat']").click(function() {
      if($(this).val()=='24 hours')
      {
         // code which replaces label with the option value       
      }
  });
```

How should the jquery look??

Comment: presumably you want the original label to be re-instated if the 12hr clock is chosen again?

Comment: In this case, I advise doubling the HTML. Use a select for each format and just show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both a `label` attribute and text content in an `<option>` element the `<label>` will take priority.

You can copy the values into the label like this:

```
$('#default-start-time option').attr('label', function() {
     return this.value;
});
```

similarly you can copy the text content back into the label like this:

```
$('#default-start-time option').attr('label', function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/cLuZa/

Note that (in Chrome, at least) neither will cause the control to change its current displayed value.  They only appear when you click on the `<select>` element again. I'm still working on that...

**EDIT** here's my final answer:

```
$("input[name='timeformat']").click(function() {
    var ampm = $(this).val() !== '24 hours';  // get mode
    var sel = $('#default-start-time')[0];    // get the <select> element

    $('option', sel).attr('label', function() {
        return ampm ? this.innerHTML : this.value;
    });

    sel.selectedIndex += 0;  // force refresh
});​
```

Comment: Thanks! looking forward for the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the states of the label based on the value selected is going to change it permanently. We need to store a reference to each the values we want to toggle inside of something that's easy to work with, so we use `data` attributes.

I don't know if you have access to the HTML, so here's the jQuery to do what we need.

```
$('#default-start-time option').each(function(index,obj){
   $(obj).data('ampm', $(obj).prop('label'));
   $(obj).data('24hr', $(obj).val());
});
```

Now, in the click function, we can toggle between the data attributes based on the value selected.

```
$("input[name='timeformat']").click(function() {
  if($(this).val()=='24 hours')
  {
      $('#default-start-time option').each(function(index,obj){
          $(obj).prop('label', $(obj).data('24hr'));
      });             
  }
  else
  {
      $('#default-start-time option').each(function(index,obj){
         $(obj).prop('label', $(obj).data('ampm'));
      });
  }
});
```

[Here is the fully working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xK7Xs/)

Comment: @codebeginner I'm quite sure it works, i've even taken it further and provided a fiddle working with the HTML you provided.

Comment: this still suffers the same problem as my answer - it doesn't change the currently displayed value until the `<select>` is clicked.  Also - you should use `.prop('label', function() { ... })` instead of `.each`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sry it does work but it suffers the problem ALnitak was speaking about

Answer (score 0):

I advise doubling the HTML and simplify the JS:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="timeformat" value="12" checked="checked" /> <b>am/pm</b> 
<input type="radio" name="timeformat" value="24" /> <b>24 hours</b>

<select id="format-12" class="">
     <option value="" selected>--Select--</option>
     <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
     <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
     <option value="01:00 AM">01:00 AM</option>
     <option value="01:30 AM">01:30 AM</option>
     <option value="04:00 PM">04:00 PM</option>
     <option value="05:30 PM">05:30 PM</option>
</select>
<select id="format-24" class="hide">
     <option value="" selected>--Select--</option>
     <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
     <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
     <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
     <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
     <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
     <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='timeformat']").on('change', function(){
    $('select[id*=format-]').toggleClass('hide');
});​
```

CSS:

```
.hide { display: none; }​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9ELJj/

Comment: the problem with this as a solution is that it then _complicates_ figuring out which of the two `<select>` tags actually has the desired value.

Comment: Truth. When it comes to form, yes.